# awk to compare files and two fields:

Tags: awk

Would like to compare first file field $4 with second file field $1 AND first file field $8 with second file field $2 .Then print match cases only from first file.

Am using two separate commands to achieve the above requirements, please suggest improving and avoiding two steps..

Input.csv

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,3456,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,3456,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,3456,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
```

master.csv

```
SendMobNum,Amount
1234,30
5678,15
2345,60
4567
8888
```

Step_1: checking first file field $4 with second file field $1

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} ($4 in a) {print $0}' master.csv Input.csv >Op_step11.csv
```

Op_step11.csv

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
```

Step_2:first file field $8 with second file field $2

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($8 in a) {print $0}' master.csv Op_step11.csv >Op_step22.csv
```

Op_step22.csv

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
```

Desired Output:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
```

Comment: your desired output seems like OR logic not AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {send[$1]; amt[$2]; next} 
    FNR == 1 || ($4 in send && $8 in amt)
' master.csv Input.csv
```

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
```